# Could not load file or assembly when deploy to lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I create the lambda function in my Visual Studio by AWS Pluggin. It run well when I debug in the local but when I deploy to the AWS and call it throws this exception:

> "errorType": "AggregateException",   "errorMessage": "One or more
>   errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.\n)",

Any though about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is assembly embedded in lambda?

Comment: Yes, it is. I checked and upload it manually into lambda function.

Comment: thanks. and which .net core are you using? maybe version you are using is not supported yet?

Comment: net core 2.1... I tested in local and it worked. I also check for the version of thats dll reference to make sure it compatible with 2.1 also :(

Comment: local test might work always, as it is not executed on AWS. Can you check contents of zip file?

Comment: I did check. It's existed on the zip folder.

Comment: one more thing. which package manager are you using?

Comment: iam using nuget right now

Comment: Try official way to deploy Lambda https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-cli-publish.html#publishing-a-net-core-lam-project-from-the-net-core-cli Then find the difference with your approach.